# Ubuntu 16.04.3 cant install package python-pkg-resources

Tags: ubuntu, python, ubuntu-16.04, apt

I'm trying to install **python-pkg-resources** in my ubuntu **16.04.3** server, but the same commands that work with 16.04.2 won't do it. The python installed is default **Python 2.7.12**

Check if python is installed

```
python --version
```

output:

```
Python 2.7.12
```

If I try this

```
sudo apt-get install python-pkg-resources
```

I get

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-pkg-resources : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                        Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

What I have already tried

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7
```

More info

```
$ apt-cache policy python
python:
  Installed: 2.7.12-1
  Candidate: 2.7.12-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.12-1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.7.11-1 500
        500 http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
aptitude update
aptitude upgrade
aptitude install python-pkg-resources
```

You may need to install aptitude, you can do this by running the following command:

```
apt install aptitude
```

Aptitude is a more intelligent packet manager that will not only manage conflicting packages for you, but will also make suggestions about different aspects of the installation.

Comment: I had to use the option n as in nasser https://askubuntu.com/questions/831074/unable-to-install-python-dev-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-using-aptitude-and-apt-get

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me before, some of the dependencies were missing on a clean install.

I was able to get it going finally using;

sudo apt autoremove 
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt update python
sudo apt upgrade python

Hope it works.

Comment: thanks, but after this process the result still the same =/